# SQL Server: create login starting with numbers

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a login & user with login name starting with number. I tried with following code but it is giving me error of "Incorrect syntax near '1000'."

```
DECLARE @uname varchar(20)
DECLARE @data int
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);

SET @data = 1000
SET @uname = CONVERT(varchar(20), @data)

SET @SQL = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + @uname + ' WITH PASSWORD = ''' + @uname + '''';

EXECUTE(@SQL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write as:

```
SET @SQL = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@uname) + ' WITH PASSWORD = ''' + @uname + '''';
```

Answer (score 1):

Write as:

```
SET @SQL = 'CREATE LOGIN [' + @uname + '] WITH PASSWORD = ''' + @uname + '''';
```